Does/will Android allow adjusting multimedia volume per app?
Windows/Linux support this. Samsung's Android has this feature. But I cannot find this in Google Android or LineageOS. Does Android not support this currently? If so, is there any plan for this in the future?
I need to play two audios from two different apps at the same time. For example, I could play LiChess while a YouTube is being played. The problem is that most apps don't support adjusting their volume levels in regard to the system volume, but simply adjust the system volume itself. So, if I raise the system volume because the YouTube video has very low volume, the sound effects of LiChess become too loud.
